# Dartlang syntax to extend a class with a mixin?

Tags: dart

Can somebody explain this dart syntax? Is this documented somewhere?

```dart
abstract class FixedLengthListBase<E> =
    ListBase<E> with FixedLengthListMixin<E>;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a form of `mixin application class` declaration.**

```
classDefinition:
  metadata abstract? class mixinApplicationClass

mixinApplicationClass:
  identifier typeParameters? '='  mixinApplication ';'
```

The mixin application may be used to extend a class;

**alternately, a class may be defined as a mixin application as described in this section.**

```
mixinApplicationClass:
  identifier typeParameters? '='  mixinApplication ';'
```

```dart
abstract class FixedLengthListBase<E> =
    ListBase<E> with FixedLengthListMixin<E>;
```

https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.trk07h8vrppk

Comment: It is just difference syntax declaration or there is some technical difference? Could you explain, please?

Answer (score 5):

This is the syntax for declaring a named mixin application. It is introduced [in the "Mixins in Dart" article](https://web.archive.org/web/20141002210912/https://www.dartlang.org/articles/mixins/).

> They are defined by a special form of class declaration that gives them a name and declares them equal to an application of a mixin to a superclass, given via a with clause.

This is (almost) the same as writing

```dart
abstract class FixedLengthListBase<E> extends
    ListBase<E> with FixedLengthListMixin<E>{}
```

The technical difference is that in this case `FixedLengthListBase` is not a mixin application itself, but an abstract subclass of the implicit, unnamed mixin application `ListBase<E> with FixedLengthListMixin<E>`